# Is there an AI engine, or API to AI engine that can create vector graphics?

Tags: api, vector-graphics, artificial-intelligence, svg, text-to-image

It's April 2023 and currently, an AI craze is going strong. 2 weeks in AI feel like 6 months in AI in any previous year. It is hard to keep up with all the models and apps getting released on a daily basis, both commercially and open-source.

Now I wonder if there is an  AI engine, or API to AI engine that can create vector graphics?

I know that GPT-3.5 can create raw SVG output if you tell it to do so. However this consumes a lot of tokens and lots of coordinate pairs can become expensive for any image that is more complex than , say a simple logo. Also you don't get a preview image and therefore it is tedious to work with GPT-3.5.

I like to work with SVG output, because it can be styled and animated with HTML and web programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Illustrator can do text-to-vector-graphic generation:

[image]

Disclaimer: I work for Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is at least one such AI service, [Vectorart.ai](https://vectorart.ai/browse), released in Summer 2023.

However, their Terms of Service are extremely beneficial for the service company. Uploaders waive copyright for their works, and let the company do what they want with uploaded files.
See copyright discussion here on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38406315).

And under the covers it is probably raster to svg conversion.